# Using date-time format for fileName in apache camel

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to use datetime format as name of the file in apache camel using fileName option. The program is not throwing any error but it is not creating any file in "output" folder. So I tried something like this  :

```
            from("stream:in?promptMessage=Enter Something:").
            to("file:C:\\output?fileName=abc.txt");
```

Running the above code generated "abc.txt" file in "output" folder. But when I am using the date syntax with fileName option in below code it is not generating any file in "output" folder.

```
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

public class Filetransfer {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {

        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            from("stream:in?promptMessage=Enter Something:").
            to("file:C:\\output?fileName=${date:now:ddMMyyyy-hh:mm:ss}.txt");
        }
    });
    while(true)
        context.start();
        //Thread.sleep(10000);
        //context.stop();
}
```

}

Comment: What version of Camel are you using? Also mind that start is not a blocking operation, so its better to do the thread sleep - or use Main class from Camel to keep a JVM running

Comment: @ClausIbsen  I am using 3.1.0 version of camel and I also tried using thread but still I am not getting any file in output folder

Answer (score 1):

The format for hours is HH(capitals). I am running camel 3.2 and this works for me:

`wireTap("file:data/out?fileName=${date:now:yyyy/MM/dd/HH-mm-ss}.json")`

Answer (score 0):

I think colons ":" in between hh & mm & ss were causing the trouble. I replaced them with "-" and now I am able to see those files generated with date and time. Thanks btw Sneharghya Pathak :)